# Error defining variable in PHP object

Tags: php

I am getting the following error in the following code:

```
Class primeField implements field {
    private $intmodulus = '';
    public function generator(){
        return ;
    }

    public function modulus(){
        return $this->$intmodulus;
    }
    public function __construct($modulus , $base=0) {
        if (is_resource($modulus) && get_resource_type($modulus) == "GMP integer"){
            $this->$intmodulus = $modulus;
        } else{
            $this->$intmodulus = gmp_init($modulus , $base); \\line 70
        }
    }
}
$a = new primeField(11);
$a->modulus();
```

Notice: Undefined variable: intmodulus in /Users/admin/PHP ECC/finitefield.php on line 70
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /Users/admin/PHP ECC/finitefield.php on line 70

Why

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is

```
$this->intmodulus
```

not `$this->$intmodulus`.

You get an error saying "cannot access empty property" because `$intmodulus` is undefined and hence accessing it gives `NULL`. The NULL gets converted into an empty string when you attempt to use it as a property name.

If the value of `$intmodulus` was the name of a valid property (e.g. if `$intmodulus == "intmodulus"`), you would be accessing the property with that name.

Comment: Note that $this->$intmodulus is still valid PHP, it just does something different from what was intended.

Comment: Thankyou, been about 3 years since I touched PHP, and my mind is a bit numb.

Answer (score 0):

`$this->$intmodulus` should be `$this->intmodulus`

See [the PHP documentation for Variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) for info on what is happening.